# How to set PATH for an apache virtualhost to include virtualenv's bin directory?

Tags: apache, virtualenv, django-compressor

I am trying to deploy my project as a virtualhost and serve it within a virtualenv. Importing and using the packages installed within the virtualenv is not a problem. But the following bit fails on the server:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', 'pyscss --output {outfile} {infile}'),
)
```

I get the following error:

```
Caught FilterError while rendering: /bin/sh: pyscss: not found
```

I tried several things I've found on the net but none of them worked. I was hopeful of `SetEnv`:

```
SetEnv PATH /path/to/virtualenv/bin:$PATH
```

But it doesn't work, my guess is because the `CompilerFilter` is using `subprocess.Popen`, but I am not sure.

How can I avoid hardcoding the pyscss executable's path and have the `bin` directory in the `PATH`, but **just for this virtualhost**?

**UPDATE:**

Apache version is **2.2.17**, mod_wsgi version is **3.3**, virtualenv version is **1.4.9**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the full path to the required 'pyscss' script, ie.:

```
/path/to/virtualenv/bin/pyscss
```

It is not overly good practice to rely on it being found in PATH for non standard programs.

If you really want to disregard that advice and rely on PATH setting anyway, in the WSGI script file do:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ':/path/to/virtualenv/bin'
```

The SetEnv directive will not work as it only sets per request variables in WSGI environ dictionary and not process global os.environ.

Comment: Thanks Graham. 1st suggestion makes sense, I'm going with it.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Apache version?

Maybe it is related with: [SetEnv does not allow PATH override](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43906)

Also, please post your environment in more detail. Are you using mod_wsgi, mod_fastcgi?

Comment: Hello Can. I've added version info.